# Anchors have unremovable underline when media query style is active

Tags: html, css

I am creating a responsive menu, in the menu i add some style using a media query when the size of the screen in less than `800px`.

So basically what i do(besides of styling) is to make the `li`'s take the whole width of the page, and those `li`'s have anchors within them.

The problem is that when the media query style is active those Anchors I mentioned suddenly have an underline even though i removed it.

Here's a fiddle with almost the same style i use(with the issue of course):
https://jsfiddle.net/shock/32jost95/3/

The Layout:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<a href="#" id="main-nav-toggler"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <u>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </u>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#main-nav {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#main-nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}
#main-nav a.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}
#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
#main-nav li {
  float: left;
}

a#main-nav-toggler {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #main-nav {
    margin: 0;
  }
  #main-nav u {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    top: 69px;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main-nav u li {
    float: none;
  }

  a#main-nav-toggler {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/NoCode.  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only provide the compiled CSS (and the necessary HTML that reproduces the problem)**.

Comment: Well, as i see it, working with css without viewing the output does not help solving the problem, and that is the reason i didn't paste the code in here. However i did provide code, but in the jsfiddle i posted,  so i think your argument is invalid. Anyways, i'll edit and add some code.

Comment: External links to code are not acceptable here.  Also, http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode.  So good job following directions?

Comment: As long as you help me solve it, down vote it how much as you want. *edit*: Awww sorry i though you actually down voted it :( i feel silly now. sorry

Comment: The reason it's not working is because you're using `<u>` instead of `<ul>` for your list..

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I must admit that i feel relay stupid right now, because even sublime text highlighted it weird(suggesting that it is an error).

Comment: Well. The u tag is a valid tag. It's just not meant for what you're using it for.. So it's not that bad! Glad I could help. Writing an answer now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `<u>` to `<ul>` for your list.

I'm assuming that this was a typo and not intentional, and is therefore not requiring any real explanation..

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've updated it for you just adding `text-decoration-color: transparent;` it not expected behavior but this the only working approach for me

https://jsfiddle.net/32jost95/4/